# Chrome : make non resizable textareas

Tags: google-chrome, textarea, firefox4

By default, Chrome makes my textareas resizable. I wish to control this and either make them only vertically resizable, or not at all.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable resizable property of textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Rails generate standard textarea tag, but Safari/Chrome (Webkit) display all (not only Rails :) textareas as resizable.

Its apperance may be disabled by CSS

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
    }
```

Or, if need only vertical resize:

```
textarea {
     resize: vertical;
     }
```

Answer (score 5):

Set `max-width` to make them only vertically resizable, or set `max-height` and `max-width` to stop all resizing.

However, be aware that breaking user expectations about how their browser treats controls tends to create a lot of user frustration.

Answer (score -3):

you can set the column and rows like

```
<%= text_area :object, :attribute, :rows => '10', :cols => '100' %> 
#=> <textarea cols="100" rows="10" id="object_attribute" name="object[attribute]">
#      #{@object.attribute}
#   </textarea>
```

or specify the size like

```
<%= text_area :object, :attribute, :size => "10x100" %> 
#=> <textarea cols="10" rows="100" id="object_attribute" name="object[attribute]">
#      #{@object.attribute}
#   </textarea>
```

Comment: And what kind of language might this be? Can't find any tags on the question about (I guess) ASP

Comment: That's erb - used in Ruby on Rails.