# How do I disable the resizable property of a textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I want to disable the resizable property of a `textarea`.

Currently, I can resize a `textarea` by clicking on the bottom right corner of the `textarea` and dragging the mouse. How can I disable this?

[image]

Comment: @JDIsaaks - further, allowing resize in certain situations can break layout and printabilit (an important aspect of a current mission-critical project).

Comment: Sometimes you really do want a non-resizeable textarea. For instance, in this case, when you're (conditionally) converting a textarea into something that just looks like a label. It looks really odd to have a label with a random floating grabber way off to the side.

Comment: For the love of all that is good, please don't do this on an actual textarea or you will alienate your power users. Breaking core browser functionality should be considered a nuclear option.

Answer (score 4307, accepted):

The following CSS rule disables resizing behavior for [`textarea`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/textarea) elements:

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

To disable it for some (but not all) `textarea`s, there are a [couple of options](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/disable-textarea-resizing-safari-chrome/).

You can use `class` attribute in your tag(`<textarea class="textarea1">`):

```css
.textarea1 {
  resize: none;
}
```

To disable a specific `textarea` with the `name` attribute set to `foo` (i.e., `<textarea name="foo"></textarea>`):

```css
textarea[name=foo] {
  resize: none;
}
```

Or, using an `id` attribute (i.e., `<textarea id="foo"></textarea>`):

```css
#foo {
  resize: none;
}
```

The [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize) lists possible values for resizing restrictions: none, both, horizontal, vertical, and inherit:

```css
textarea {
  resize: vertical; /* user can resize vertically, but width is fixed */
}
```

Review a decent [compatibility page](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/) to see what browsers currently support this feature. As Jon Hulka has commented, the dimensions can be [further restrained](http://davidwalsh.name/textarea-resize) in CSS using max-width, max-height, min-width, and min-height.

> #### Super important to know:
>
> This property does nothing unless the overflow property is something other than visible, which is the default for most elements. So generally to use this, you'll have to set something like overflow: scroll;
>
> Quote by Sara Cope,
> http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/r/resize/

Comment: Is there a solution for Firefox, Opera and/or IE?

Comment: @Šime IE and FF3 (and earlier) do not add support resizing, so a solution for them is not needed. For FF4, this solution should work.

Comment: as per http://davidwalsh.name/textarea-resize - use resize:vertical or resize:horizontal to constrain resizing to one dimension. Or use any of max-width, max-height, min-width and min-height.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it weird to set this using css and not attributes? Why can't I then set disabled or checked or other properties using CSS ...

Comment: @Buksy Because "disabled" is a state, not a visual property. Thus it's logical that it shouldn't be decided by a *styling* language.

Comment: This solution haven´t the best practices. You can do it with a MVC property. @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.YourProperty, new { @style = "width: 90%; height: 180px; resize: none;" })

Comment: I initially attempted the above technique, but it did not work for me, so I then used 
  textarea {
    resize: none;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
That`s working perfectly fine on https://www.fireboxtools.com/tools/word-counter

Answer (score 251):

In CSS:

```css
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 135):

I found two things:

First

```
textarea{resize: none}
```

This is a CSS 3, *which is not released yet*, compatible with [**Firefox 4 (and later), Chrome, and Safari**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp).

Another format feature is to [`overflow: auto`](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=85786) to get rid of the right scrollbar, taking into account the [*dir*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp) attribute.

### Code and different browsers

*Basic HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea style="overflow:auto;resize:none" rows="13" cols="20"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

*Some browsers*

- Internet Explorer 8

[image]

- Firefox 17.0.1

[image]

- Chrome

[image]

Answer (score 75):

CSS 3 has a new property for UI elements that will allow you to do this. The property is the [resize property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize). So you would add the following to your stylesheet to disable resizing of all textarea elements:

```
textarea { resize: none; }
```

This is a CSS 3 property; use a [compatibility chart](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) to see browser compatibility.

Personally, I would find it very annoying to have resizing disabled on textarea elements. This is one of those situations where the designer is trying to "break" the user's client. If your design can't accommodate a larger textarea, you might want to reconsider how your design works. Any user can add `textarea { resize: both !important; }` to their user stylesheet to override your preference.

Comment: But that would be the user _intentionally breaking_ their layout, rather than a user who just needs to resize his/her `texarea` and ends up making something not work

Answer (score 34):

```
<textarea style="resize:none" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Text" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 28):

If you need deep support, you can use an old school technique:

```css
textarea {
    max-width: /* desired fixed width */ px;
    min-width: /* desired fixed width */ px;
    min-height: /* desired fixed height */ px;
    max-height: /* desired fixed height */ px;
    resize: none; /* If you wnt to hide the handle in the lower right corner */;
}
```

Comment: Also use `resize:none` with this solution to prevent the handle appearing in the bottom corner which frustratingly doesn't work.

Answer (score 24):

This can be done in HTML easily:

```
<textarea name="textinput" draggable="false"></textarea>
```

This works for me. The default value is `true` for the `draggable` attribute.

Comment: This is an HTML 5 attribute, so only newer browsers will support. I read somewhere IE supports it from 9 onwards.

Comment: This working in most browsers. in every latest browser.

Comment: it won't prevent textarea from resizing

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea This isn't working on latest Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/ps2v8df9/

Answer (score 17):

You simply use: `resize: none;` in your **CSS**.

> The **resize** property specifies whether or not an element is resizable
> by the user.
>
> **Note:** The resize property applies to elements whose computed overflow
> value is something other than "visible".

Also **resize** not supported in **Internet Explorer**  at the moment.

Here are different properties for resize:

**No Resize:**

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

**Resize both ways (vertically & horizontally):**

```
textarea {
  resize: both;
}
```

**Resize vertically:**

```
textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}
```

**Resize horizontally:**

```
textarea {
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

Also if you have `width` and `height` in your CSS or HTML, it will prevent your textarea be resized, with a broader browsers support.

Answer (score 14):

Use this property  `resize: none;`

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can simply **disable the textarea** property like this:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

To disable **vertical** or **horizontal** resizing, use

```
resize: vertical;
```

or

```
resize: horizontal;
```

Answer (score 10):

To disable the resize property, use the following CSS property:

```
resize: none;
```

- You can either apply this as an inline style property like so:

  ```
  <textarea style="resize: none;"></textarea>
  ```
- or in between `<style>...</style>` element tags like so:

  ```
  textarea {
      resize: none;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 10):

you need to set the below CSS code in your `component.css`

```css
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

The code above will disable the resizable property of all `<textarea/>` elements in your project. If you want that that is fine, otherwise you would want to use a specific class for your textarea elements.

```css
.not-resizable {
   resize: none;
}
```

In your HTML

```
<textarea class="not-resizable"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 7):

CSS 3 can solve this problem. Unfortunately it's only supported on [60% of used browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=resize) nowadays.

For Internet Explorer and iOS you can't turn off resizing, but you can limit the `textarea` dimension by setting its `width` and `height`.

```
/* One can also turn on/off specific axis. Defaults to both on. */
textarea { resize:vertical; } /* none|horizontal|vertical|both */
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/doxk6Lnq/)

Answer (score 7):

To disable resize for all `textarea`s:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

To disable resize for a specific `textarea`, add an attribute, `name`, or an `id` and set it to something. In this case, it is named `noresize`

#### HTML

```
<textarea name='noresize' id='noresize'> </textarea>
```

#### CSS

```
/* Using the attribute name */
textarea[name=noresize] {
    resize: none;
}
/* Or using the id */

#noresize {
    resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can disable resizeable property of textarea using **textarea {resize: none;}**

```
textarea {
   resize: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://www.codesprogram.com/snippet/98e0Ha)

Answer (score 6):

I have created a small demo to show how resize properties work. I hope it will help you and others as well.

```css
.resizeable {
  resize: both;
}

.noResizeable {
  resize: none;
}

.resizeable_V {
  resize: vertical;
}

.resizeable_H {
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="resizeable" rows="5" cols="20" name="resizeable" title="This is Resizable.">
This is Resizable. Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.
</textarea>

<textarea class="noResizeable" rows="5" title="This will not Resizable. " cols="20" name="resizeable">
This will not Resizable. Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.
</textarea>

<textarea class="resizeable_V" title="This is Vertically Resizable." rows="5" cols="20" name="resizeable">
This is Vertically Resizable. Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.
</textarea>

<textarea class="resizeable_H" title="This is Horizontally Resizable." rows="5" cols="20" name="resizeable">
This is Horizontally Resizable. Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

With `@style`, you can give it a custom size and disable the resize feature `(resize: none;)`.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.YourProperty, new { @style = "width: 90%; height: 180px; resize: none;" })
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, next time please format the code.

Comment: This is asp.net MVC based answer. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with jQuery also

```
$('textarea').css("resize", "none");
```

Comment: You should [use more jquery](https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif). You're not using it enough. :)

Comment: [It is a meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492) - e.g., *"You should totally drop that and try jQuery."*.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `!important` makes it work:

```
width:325px !important; height:120px !important; outline:none !important;
```

`outline` is just to avoid the blue outline on certain browsers.

Comment: Don't abuse `!important` attribute. Meaningless to fix the width & height if  CSS attribute `resize: none` can remove the resize feature

Comment: Isn't `!important` evil?

Comment: In current Chrome this stop horizontal resizing, but I can still resize textarea vertically.

Comment: In some rare cases this could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a way to this in plain Javascript:

```
textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
textArea_input.setAttribute("style","resize:none");
```

Note: Setting the style property this way will overwrite all your prior css style declarations.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can disable the resizable property of a textarea using CSS. The following code will disable the resizable property of a textarea with the id `my-textarea`:

CSS Code:-

```
textarea#my-textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

You can also disable the resizable property of all `textareas` on a page by adding the following code to your CSS stylesheet:

CSS Code:-

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

The `resize` property can have three values:

- `none`: The textarea cannot be resized.
- `horizontal`: The text area can only be resized horizontally.
- `vertical`: The text area can only be resized vertically.

The default value of the `resize` property is `none`.

In addition to using CSS, you can also disable the resizable property of a textarea using JavaScript. The following code will disable the resizable property of a textarea with the id `my-textarea`:

JavaScript Code:-

```
const textarea = document.getElementById('my-textarea');
textarea.style.resize = 'none';
```

This code will overwrite any CSS styles that have been applied to the textarea.

To reduce the size of a textarea, you can use the `rows` and `cols` attributes in the HTML code. The rows attribute specifies the number of `rows` in the textarea, and the `cols` attribute specifies the number of columns. For example, the following code will create a textarea with 10 rows and 50 columns:

HTML Code:-

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

You can also use CSS to set the size of a textarea. The following code will set the height and width of a textarea with the id `my-textarea` to 100px and 200px, respectively:

CSS Code:-

```
textarea#my-textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```