# Any way to disable Firefox 4 textarea-resizing handles?

Tags: firefox, resize, textarea

I have a site with a textarea that is a very specific size; resizing it could make the user think that they can enter more text into the textarea than is possible (it is limited by rows and columns).  Firefox 4 automatically shows a 'resize handle' in the bottom-right of the textbox and as a user I can resize the textarea on the page.  Is there any way to disable this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable resizable property of textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use CSS and style it with:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: That is beautiful, a much more elegant solution than I was expecting!

Comment: BTW: Works in Safari and Chrome as well.

Comment: For someone seeking an answer to go this cross-browser, kindly set the max-width and max-length values for the same. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the CSS will not work. I have successfully removed the users ability to resize the textbox by using an inline style. Those are the last ones processed by the browser and have the final say on what style is used.