# How to style resizers

Tags: javascript, html, css

You know those three lines in the bottom corner of a `textarea` / `div` that indicate it can be resized? The ones like [these](http://brett.batie.com/wp-content/uploads/textarea-chrome.png). I want to restyle this icon so the resize functionality of my div is much more obvious. Perhaps something like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/06/image64.png). How do I remove these lines while retaining the resize functionality of my div?

I've tried googling and searching SO. The closest I found to someone else asking the same question was this guy, [but the best answer suggested turning off resize altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340545/how-to-remove-dots-present-at-the-right-bottom-corner-of-the-textarea-html), which is not what I want.

Comment: Well if you hide those lines, textarea can't be resized anyway so i can't understand why you want to hide them and keep textarea resizable

Comment: I have a div in my app I want to make resizeable. But I want something better than those hard to see lines in the bottom corner, to make abundantly clear to the user that this is a resizeable div. The div is black which makes the lines quite hard to see.

Comment: Perhaps you're saying that it's just not possible? :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Obs:* This answer is for WebKit only, couldn't find for other browsers nor testing with their - names worked.

---

Not with standard css. The resizer widget, like scrollbars, is typically from OS. You may be able to style it with custom browser selectors, however, that depends on the browser. Webkit can do some limited styling by using the [::-webkit-resizer](https://www.google.com.co/?q=webkit-resizer) selector.

```css
textarea::-webkit-resizer {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/hQZDwHs.png);
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Also, you can set `background-color`

```css
textarea::-webkit-resizer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

---

**Extra**

1. You can read [emulating frame-resize behavior with divs using jQuery
   without using jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673348/emulating-frame-resize-behavior-with-divs-using-jquery-without-using-jquery-ui/) post to emulate frame-resize, here you
   will have more possibilities.
2. `-moz-resizer` does not work on Firefox 46.0.1. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04hzbf16/).
3. All (or most of) [Shadow DOM selectors](https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334).

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I already knew how to restyle scrollbars and hoped there was something similar for resizers.

Comment: @Gaweyne note that webkit will work on Chrome, but not Firefox (if you care about that).

Comment: @Gaweyne `-moz-resizer` does not work on Firefox 46.0.1. https://jsfiddle.net/04hzbf16/

Answer (score 0):

You can have a textarea set to a auto resize and removing the resize handler: Follow instructions here:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/TextareaTricks/

Note that this icon is generated by browser and is not a part of HTML Spec. So you can hide or show it, but you cant change its appearance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: nanilab's answer shows how you can in fact restyle this icon, just like scrollbars.

Comment: @Gaweyne but only avalaible for webkit :)

Comment: Yeah but Internet Explorer for the lose. We actually refuse to support Internet Explorer in our app at work. ^_^

Comment: @Gaweyne i use FF :)

Comment: Internet Explorer still in use by millions. If a solution is not cross-browser, it does not consider a solution.

Comment: @Shah Ghafoori This is true but for our specific product and our specific clients (who are NOT average internet users or the general public) telling them to "get chr0me" or "git firef0x" is perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<div class="form-group resizer">
                <div class="arrow-resizer-textarea"></div>
                <textarea id="mytextArea" class="form-control" placeholder="text here....."></textarea>
            </div>
```

**sass**

```
textarea {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 1141px;
  min-height: 58px;
}

.resizer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 8px solid #1c87c7;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    right: -3px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
.arrow-resizer-textarea {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid #1c87c7;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  right: -3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}
```