# How to disable textarea resizing?

Tags: html, css

I need to disable textarea horizontal resize. Sometimes I want to allow vertical resize on the textarea.

Whenever I create a contact us page the textarea is making  my design ugly.

could any one give me a solution to disable it please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable resizable property of textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

Answer (score 433, accepted):

You can use CSS.

Disable all:

```
textarea { resize: none; }
```

Only vertical resize:

```
textarea { resize: vertical; }
```

Only horizontal resize:

```
textarea { resize: horizontal; }
```

Disable vertical and horizontal with limit:

```
textarea { resize: horizontal; max-width: 400px; min-width: 200px; }
```

Disable horizontal and vertical with limit:

```
textarea { resize: vertical; max-height: 300px; min-height: 200px; }
```

I think `min-height` should be useful for you.

Comment: Awesome! If you don't want to mess with min-width, you can use the `rows=""` attribute to define a specific height in numbers.

Answer (score 53):

With some css like this

```
textarea
{
   resize: none;
}
```

Or if you want only vertical

```
textarea { resize:vertical; }
```

Or horizontal

```
textarea { resize:horizontal; }
```

or both ( not your case)

```
textarea { resize:both; }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can put this in the CSS file:

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

disable `horizontal` and `vertical` with limit

```
textarea { 
    width:100%;
    resize:vertical; 
    max-height:250px; 
    min-height:100px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `textarea` I used `width: 500px !important` and `height: 350px !important`, so this `CSS` codes prevent user resize, but if you have other tags you must use `resize: none`, for complete explanations read [This Link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/r/resize/).

For example, for a `p` tag you must set `overflow` property with a value that is not `visible` and then set `resize`, `none`, `both`, `vertical`, `horizontal`.