# How can I reset the size of textarea when close the popup modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form in popup modal. When I resize the textarea then close the popup modal and after that when I reopen the popup model its textArea is not in proper form.
I want to reset the size of textarea. Please help me out On the same issue.

[image]

Comment: You can give textarea resize:none, it will prevent resizing the textarea.

Comment: can you post your css?

Comment: textarea resize is also needed

Comment: You mean like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087841/1823841)

Comment: Check if have a cols inline... set textarea{ width: 100% !important}

Comment: make the width of that textbox as 100% using css.

Comment: Hi vel,

textarea{
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
 line-height: inherit;
 margin: 0px;
 overflow: auto;
 color: inherit;
}

Comment: To get rid of the cols inline, use this jQuery (example) : $( "textarea" ).removeAttr( "cols" );

Comment: @palaѕн mentioned another stack for this...which will work?

Comment: yes. @LuisP.A. suggestion is works.

Comment: it should be reset the size when close the popup modal...

Comment: why dont you set width of `model-some value` to textarea

Comment: You might want to restrict the size of the textarea as in this ticket answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382245/how-to-disable-textarea-resizing

Comment: there is nothing any re-sizable issue... 
its size *reset* issue after close popup modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can define in which direction the textarea can be resized by the [CSS resize Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp)

```html
<textarea style="resize:both">Can be resized in every direction</textarea><br>
<textarea style="resize:vertical">Can be resized in vertical direction</textarea><br>
<textarea style="resize:horizontal">Can be resized in horizontal direction</textarea><br>
<textarea style="resize:none">Can not be resized</textarea>
```