# How to make <textarea>s un-expandable using HTML?

Tags: html

`textareas` are expandable (bottom right corner there is a hook).

How do I make a textarea `solid/un-expandable`?
Preferably through HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea

Comment: i found the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this in your CSS:-

```
textarea { resize: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea { resize: none; }
```

Is good and does work.