# How can I prevent a textarea resize handle from showing through higher z-index div?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'd like to have a hidden `<textarea>` element on my page to handle user input while displaying it in a custom way. I thought I'd be able to do this by giving it a lower z-index than the element I'm hiding it behind (yes, the element is positioned too) . Indeed, the `textarea` is hidden appropriately. However... when enough text is entered to necessitate a scrollbar, the resize handle (grip) icon shows up on top of the masking `<div>`! (At least, on chrome.)

[image][image]

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9HB4C/) to play around with.

How can I stop this from happening? The handle doesn't actually allow resizing, so it seems very odd it would pop to the top depending on content length.

Additionally, is there a more canonical way of hiding a text input field?

Comment: Why not just remove the resize handle all together? I believe it is `resize: none`. I don't see it in Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but I don't see the handle appear. Tested fiddle in FF and Chrome

Comment: See this one. It will helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea

Comment: As I commented on @RamRaider's answer, `resize:none` causes a scrollbar to flash through the masking divs each time a new line is needed in the textarea (either through hitting enter or just text wrapping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should disable the resize handle entirely - but using clip() you could hide the scrollbar

```
<style>
 textarea{ 
   position: absolute;
   left:10px;
   top:10px;
   z-index:-1;
   resize:none;
   width:200px;
   height:50px;
   clip:rect(0,189px, 50px, 0);
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Rather than using a div to hide a portion of the textarea, could you not use clip? 
textarea{
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    z-index:-1;
    resize:none;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    clip:rect(0,189px, 50px, 0);
}

Comment: I'll also point out that by solving the problem with clipping, it is no longer necessary to set the `z-index` or `resize:none`, and no extra div is needed to hide it behind.

Comment: Is this just a bug that hasn't been fixed in a few years or is it behaving as expected?  I have this issue as well but the clip isn't going to work as easily because my textarea is sized dynamically.  Seems funny that this same problem exists a couple years later when it seems to be a clear bug (although maybe it is operating as expected for some reason I don't understand).

Answer (score 2):

for those who arrived here looking for a way to hide the resize icon, use:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```