# How to disable resize textarea in django?

Tags: html, django, django-widget

I'm trying to disable resize to the textarea widget in django, this is my form:

```
class VForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Visions
        widgets = {'vision': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':6,
                                                   'cols':22,
                                                   'resize':'none'}),
        }
```

Adding the resize property to none isn't working

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable resizable property of textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

Comment: @AamirAdnan not sure if it is a duplicate. The question is django-specific.

Comment: Why could be this a duplicate? I'm asking if it is possible through django widget attr

Comment: No problem, i found the answer that i've been looking

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to add a style attribute:

```
 widgets = {'vision': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':6,
                                            'cols':22,
                                            'style':'resize:none;'}),
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in your CSS:

```
.no-resize {
    resize: none;
}
```

And this in your Python to add the class:

```py
class VForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Visions

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This has been overridden to customise the textarea form widget.
        """
        super(VForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['vision'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'no-resize'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way is using `style` instead of `class`:

```
class VForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Visions
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        super(VForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['vision'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'resize:none'
```