# How do I make the input more like a textarea, though without the expanding icon (bottom right)?

Tags: html, css

I have this text input in a form:

```
<input type="text" rows="3" />
```

I am trying to get it to take multiple lines of input. Though the user can only (at the moment) enter text on one line.

**How do I make the input more like a textarea, though without the expanding text area icon (bottom right)?**

I would like this:
[image: textarea]

Not this:
[image: textarea]

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea></textarea>

textarea {
 resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you out with the resize issue:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

For styling, try google. :)