# How to set a maximum in a textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I am trying to make a textarea but I want to make it so the user cannot make it bigger or smaller. I still want them to be able to type in it. Just not control the textarea with the little control button in the bottom right corner. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the `resize` property of your textarea to `none`:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

---

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
  At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>
```

Comment: @zacharyfoster You're welcome. Please mark my answer as the correct one so that users can know your query has been answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
textarea { resize: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with `resize: none` set on `textarea`