# How to set fixed width and "custom-resizeable" length to Spring <form:textarea />?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I've digged a lot but still didn't found answer for my case.
I have some model window, inside of it I have some textarea:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="groupDescription" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Description: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <form:textarea path="groupDescription" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors path="groupDescription" />
    </div>
</div>
```

It automatically have the same width as input forms in this window, this is good. But! I can resize it, so it can be outside of modal window borders. 
How can I disable this **width** resizing? For length I would like to set some option like "length is 2 rows, but no more than 10 rows". Can you help?
Also, can I do it without JavaScript?
Thanks in advance! :)

**P.S.** Sorry, I've needed to edit title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable resizable property of textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

Comment: Close, but not exactly! I've read this one, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `resize: vertical;`, this will allow vertical resize only.

Comment: Oh, really... Sorry. But I still need to know how to set "length is 2 rows, but no more than 10 rows"...

Comment: I realy don't know how to set maxrows, but you can try `max-height:`

Comment: Yes, it works with  `max-height:`. Not as I expected, but I can accept this solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the `textarea` from resizing you can simply add the CSS attribute to your textarea class `resize: none;` .

Apart from this `<form:textarea>` has no difference with the html textarea , it rendered as normal textarea in the browser. you can check that by inspecting it the browser source.

You can use `resize: vertical;` to allow only resizing its length

Comment: Yes, you right! But! I want to disallow only width resizing, not length too... For length it would be better to set some option like "length is 2 rows, but no more than 10 rows". Can you help with this?

Comment: Updated my answer have a look at

Comment: Good! And how about "length is 2 rows, but no more than 10 rows", do you know how to do it?