# Prevent textarea from scaling fieldset

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form with a `textarea` input inside of it. When I scale the `textarea` it pushed the `fieldset` boundary with it. How can I untie the `textarea` scale from the `fieldset` scale. I want this only to apply to the horizontal scale.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Description</legend>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text">
        <p></p>
        <label>Describe the object</label>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
textarea {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nv155x7/)**

Comment: I see you edited your question. If you want to set the limitation only on the horizontal scale, just use the div part of my answer, with the ".DontGrowWidth" css class. It will enable you to change the textarea size without changing the fieldset size

Answer (score 2):

Add max-height to the fieldset, it will take care of the height.
It won't work with the width so you will have to work around it and wrap your text area wit a div and set it's max-witdh to the value of your fieldset.

```
<h1>Form Demo</h1>
  <p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>User Information</legend>
      <label>Sex</label>
      <input type="radio"
             name="sex"
             id="male"
             value="male"/>
      <label for="male">Male</label>
      <input type="radio"
             name="sex"
             id="female"
             value="female"/>
      <label for="female">Female</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="DontGrow">
      <legend>Description</legend>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text">
      <p></p>
      <label>Describe the object</label>
      <div class="DontGrowWidth">
          <textarea></textarea>
      <div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

css:

```
body {
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
label:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight:bold;
}

.DontGrow{
    height:160px;
    max-height:160px;

}

.DontGrowWidth{
      max-width: 300px;
}

}
fieldset {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
input {
  display: block;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: inline
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is keep on repeating

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

[How to disable resizable property of textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

Learn to explore and search first before asking question. Google it!

Comment: Well genius, If you had read the question you would know that my goal is not to disable the resize option.

Comment: Duuh? As I can see on your demo image or whatever you want to get rid of that grabber thing that resize the scale of your textarea that pushes the boundary of the div of you wrapper. Am i correct ?

Comment: no.... I want to keep the text area scaling but get rid of the outline scaling with it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by wrapping the `textarea` in a div container and restraining this container in size.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="textareas">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.textareas {
  width: 300px;
}
```

[image]