# Adjusting fixed-width containers on textarea resizing

Tags: html, css

I am creating a two-column layout by having one div floating left (with a width of almost 50%) and another div floating right. Inside these divs I am displaying a textarea. This works fine in principle and nicely adjusts the width of the columns to the available width.

However, when someone uses the browser's textarea resizing function (e.g. in Firefox) to change the size of the textarea, the div does not adjust. The result of this is that the text area is resized, but extends outside the div (or just becomes cut off).

Can I fix this somehow?

MWE:

```html
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
     <div style="float: left; width: 40%; background: red; padding: 1em;">
      <textarea style="width: 100%">left</textarea>
     </div>
     <div style="float: right; width: 40%; background: green; padding: 1em;">
      <textarea style="width: 100%">right</textarea>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: And do you want allow users to extend textarea size?

Comment: You could disable the `textarea` resize: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea

Comment: No, I want to allow resizing.

Answer (score 1):

You can only permit the vertical resizing to avoid your problem.

**CSS**

```
textarea { resize:vertical; }
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bsq769v9/11/)**

If you want to disble the resizing do this:

**CSS**

```
textarea { resize:none; }
```

If you want to have the resizing and expand the div you should use `min-height`instead `width`:

**HTML**

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="float: left; min-width: 40%; background: red; padding: 1em;">
        <textarea style="width: 100%">left</textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; min-width: 40%; background: green; padding: 1em;">
        <textarea style="width: 100%">right</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bsq769v9/12/)**

Comment: Thanks, but I do actually want to allow resizing.

Comment: It´s simple, you can set `min-width:40%` instead `width: 40%` - check it out - https://jsfiddle.net/bsq769v9/12/

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the horizontal resizing of text area

```
textarea {
  resize: vertical; /* you can resize vertically, but not horizontal */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do actually want to allow resizing.

Comment: set max-width: 100%; for textarea