# HTML textarea tag size changing

Tags: html, css

So, I'm using the *textarea* tag and I would like to ask a few things:

1) Any user can change the size of the box, but can it be prevented? If yes, how?

2) Is it possible to (*without preventing the size-changing of the box*) set the **maximum** height or width?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it in the first place? The possibility exists for the user's convenience, e.g. if they use enlarged fonts. It has zero impact on the data that is transmitted. Either way, always remember to Google - `HTML textarea prevent resize` will get you everything you need

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea

Answer (score 1):

To disable the resizing of your textarea use `resize:none;` and to control the max width and height, use `max-height` and `max-width` properties in CSS.

```css
textarea.noResize{
  resize:none;  
}
textarea.heightControl{
  max-height:100px;
  max-width:500px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="noResize"></textarea>
<textarea class="heightControl"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable resizing of the text area and control the max size add this to your css file :

```
textarea {
   resize: none;
   max-height : 100px;
   max-width : 100px;
}
```

Just adjust the pixel values to what you wish it to be. However keep note: this could be annoying to some users if they wish to modify the size of the textarea.