# Disable scroll on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I'm trying to make the textarea unscrollable but i'm unable to find a way
to get the textarea unscrollable.

I've made a simple example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6am6dze/)

```
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable resizable property of textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add in the css file:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

or:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="45" placeholder="Animatie:" name="description" style="resize: none"></textarea>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p6am6dze/2/

Comment: That just removes the resize handle, but doesn't affect scrolling. The jsfiddle example will still scroll if you go past the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="45" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;"  placeholder="Animatie:" name="description" ></textarea>
```

style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;", this will fulfill your requirement hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

For no resizing at all, see Luiz's answer.

For resizing in only one direction, use:

```
textarea { resize: vertical; }

textarea { resize: horizontal; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but I have a solution in case what you just want is to remove the scrollbar but keep the resize property. You do:

```
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
   dipsplay: none;
}
```

and the scrollbar will not show. The resize seems to still show for me **until** the text content requires scroll.

```css
textarea {
width: 50%;
height: 70px;
resize: vertical;
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display:none;
 }
```

```html
<p>Add as much text as you want</p>
<textarea></textarea>
```

**NOTE:** You can still scroll, it jsut doesn't show the scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
textarea {
resize: none;
}
</style>
```