# How do you disable resize of an Angular 2 Material md-textarea element?

Tags: angular, material-design

I'm unable to disable res-zing on an md-textarea. This is how I've been trying:

```
<md-textarea md-no-resize rows="3"></md-textarea>
```

Doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 5):

You can add the following css to disable the feature entirely - as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

`textarea {
    resize: none;
}`

Working plunkr example: https://plnkr.co/edit/r5JhFNd4hKCk6QqTL27B?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm.... we may be on the right track. I set min-width: 100%, and that stopped the width from shrinking, but max-width and min/max-height don't seem to have an effect. Also removing that drag-icon in the bottom-right of the text area would be awesome, and would prevent any resizing at all.

Comment: I have updated my answer to do what you want it to :)

Comment: At the moment I've screwed up some files in the project and it all fell apart. Once it's all back up and running I'll test this out. I'm 90% sure that I did this and it had no effect, but I will keep you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
 <textarea matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows="9" matAutosizeMaxRows="9" </textarea>
```

Comment: It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.

Comment: it looks self-explanatory so an explanation would be redundant

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling autogrow like this:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <textarea ng-model="" md-maxlength="250" rows="3" md-select-on-focus md-no-autogrow>
    </textarea>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: this is a detective's job. what's the change? and the reason?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)