# How do I make the height of an input field match the height of other fields?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input, height

At the moment I am working on a website on which you can book tours.
My problem is that I want a certain input field to match the height of other input fields next to it.
To clarify my problem, see the picture below:
[Booking form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPEwB.png)
As you can see, I want the "Comments" input field to match the total height of the other input fields next to it, indicated by the blue lines. Is there any way I can make this happen? This form is only using bootstrap 3, no additional CSS. I don't mind adding additional CSS if needed. HTML provided below. Important to say is that this website is also used on mobile, so I would prefer not to set the height to an amount of pixels (since it needs to be responsive).

HTML:

```
<form>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3>Contact Details:</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fullname">Full name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="Full name" name="fullname">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phonenumber">Phone number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone number" name="phonenumber">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Book Now</button>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-7">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3>Any questions or comments?</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comments">Write your questions or comments here:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: `#comments` should be a `textarea`, not a text `input`

Comment: @MichaelCoker I tried it, but the textarea is resizable and I don't want that. Thank you for the comment though!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thank you!