# How to remove whitespace around vertical scrollbar of TextArea?

Tags: java, css, gwt

I need some help to fix one issue, issue is an white-space around vertical scrollbar on resizing the text area. I need the vertical scrollbar on removing the white space.
Can you please help me how to remove that? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: it's not a whitespace, it's the icon that allow you to resize

Comment: Thanks @temaniAfif, can we hide that? on enabling resizing and vertical scrollbar

Comment: make the element not resizable if you want to hide it

Comment: if I use overflow: hidden, the white space is hiding but the scrollbar is not coming. If any chance I need to fix this issue by removing the resize white space and enable vertical scrollbar

Comment: See [How to disable resizable property of textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea): in CSS: `resize: none; overflow: auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> Note: it will only change it's background-color not hide & only work in `webkit`.

```
textarea::-webkit-resizer {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

**Or**

You can use `js`.