# how can I prevent users form extending/ minimizing TextField Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How can I prevent this from happening

[image: I am talking about this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Django `TextField` is rendered as a HTML `textarea`.

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5235160/9225671) question, you could use `style="resize: none;"`.

If you would like to add that in your views/form (and not in the templates), you could try something like:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_field_name'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'resize: none;'
```

or if you have a form instance

```
form.fields['my_field_name'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'resize: none;'
```